# Websphere ClassCastException

Tags: java, websphere, classcastexception

I'm uplifting an application, and it's working on Tomcat. On WAS 7, I'm hitting a few issues. The stacktrace is below. I'm using a parent last class loader for the application. I've been googling and tried a number of things I've seen there but with no help. Any ideas please?

```
[8/10/15 9:40:38:758 EDT] 0000001a extension     E com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor createServletWrapper Error occured while preparing the servlet for initialization. 
                                 java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1795)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:1038)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:959)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:740)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1272)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5263)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5441)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1277)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2048)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:385)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:328)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:561)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1074)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:955)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.java:236)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fullAppUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1682)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:723)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:575)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1915)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1424)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:665)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1954)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1902)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.action.SyncWorkSpaceAction.execute(SyncWorkSpaceAction.java:273)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:228)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:215)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:401)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:618)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:565)
    at com.core.fw.dao.AbstractDaoFileImpl.loadDataIntoCache(AbstractDaoFileImpl.java:78)
    at com.common.fileloader.AbstractFileSeedDataLoaderImpl.registerURLs(AbstractFileSeedDataLoaderImpl.java:138)
    at com.common.fileloader.AbstractFileSeedDataLoaderImpl.init(AbstractFileSeedDataLoaderImpl.java:60)
    at com.core.fw.dao.AbstractDaoFileImpl.<init>(AbstractDaoFileImpl.java:68)
    at com.common.configmgr.dao.AppConfigDaoXMLImpl.<init>(AppConfigDaoXMLImpl.java:58)
    at com.common.configmgr.XMLBasedConfigManagerBuilder.buildConfigurationManagerFactory(XMLBasedConfigManagerBuilder.java:46)
    at com.common.configmgr.ConfigurationManagerFactory.createConfigurationManagerAdapter(ConfigurationManagerFactory.java:122)
    at com.common.configmgr.ConfigurationManagerFactory.getConfigurationManager(ConfigurationManagerFactory.java:103)
    at com.common.logging.AbstractLoggerHelper.<init>(AbstractLoggerHelper.java:44)
    at org.slf4j.impl.AdfLog4jLoggerAdapter.<init>(AdfLog4jLoggerAdapter.java:34)
    at org.slf4j.impl.AdfLog4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(AdfLog4jLoggerFactory.java:44)
    at org.slf4j.impl.AdfLog4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(AdfLog4jLoggerFactory.java:30)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:277)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:370)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:246)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:167)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:184)
    at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1909)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1900)
    ... 96 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory
    at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:837)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    ... 137 more
```

Comment: do you have your project in some IDE ? if so try to change its runtime target and bounded server to WebSphere, also check libraries if there are any Tomcat libraries.

Comment: Get rid of any xerces jars that have in your WEB-INF/lib directory. It/they are almost certainly redundant

Comment: Have you checked your websphere version has [fixpacks 6.1.0.37 and 7.0.0.17](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM27213) ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. I can't change my IDE to point to WS as it's on a different machine which I can't connect to. I upload a war file that is created in the IDE. I don't think I can remove the xerces files from the web-inf without breaking the application. I have no checked for those fixes. We did update to Feature Pack one - we are on 7.0.0.23 at the moment. I will check with the relevant people to get those installed or check if they are. Thanks

Comment: If you deploy to WAS, you should develop on WAS not on Tomcat. This usually leads to problems as in your case. WebSphere is full Java EE server and contains lots of features not available by default in Tomcat. Adding third party engines to WebSphere apps results usually in classloader conflicts.

Comment: If you cant remove xerces related libraries, try to set Parent Last for the web module, not whole application.